# How to step one step back in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Is it possible to step backwards through executed code in a debug session?

For example I step over a method called `abc()` expecting to get `12` but after re-checking the value returned I notice it's `5` instead of `12`. How can I step back to where I was before and step into the method to see what is going on?  I know you can do this in visual studio but I can't find how to do this in intelliJ.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can drop the frames until you reach the point where you want to be. This isn't exactly stepping backwards, but it is quite similar in a lot of respects.

Though as the comments mention below, this will not revert the global state of your application -- which isn't a huge concern if you're developing stateless services, but could be if you're developing swing applications (if anyone actually does that any more).

On the debugger toolbar it looks like this: [image: Drop Frame]. In `Idea 2016.3` the drop-frame icon changed to look like this [image: drop frame in idea 2016.3], and since `2019.3` it changed to look like this [image].

Full documentation is available here: [IntelliJ Debugger Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debug-tool-window.html), and there is a [StackOverflow Drop Frame Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367816/when-using-the-java-debugger-in-intellij-what-does-drop-frame-mean), with a few useful answers

Comment: Didn't find it. Isn't it available anymore ?

Comment: The icon has changed, but it's still there. It's a box with a red x in the top left.

Comment: "it is functionally equivalent" - This is wrong. Dropping frames won't, for instance, revert static or field variables. It will only revert local variables. One must be aware of this before using this feature.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3: I found it by right-clicking on a stack frame in the debugger, not on the debugger toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Chronon Debugger plugin which actually allows you to step back, not just drop the frame
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/try-chronon-debugger-with-intellij-idea-13-1-eap/

Comment: I've tried this now, and I think it's really quite poor. The idea seems good at first, but it seems not to really work./