# How to step out in a multithreaded program IntelliJ

Tags: multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea

I know I can drop a frame to "step out" like you can "step in" in a single threaded program. However I tried dropping a frame in my multithreaded program and it doesn't go back to where it was. why is this?

There are explanations for single threaded stepping outs here:
[How to step one step back in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867491/how-to-step-one-step-back-in-intellij)

and is in the tutorial for intelliJ too:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/05/debugger-basics-in-intellij-idea/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I just need to drop the frame as soon as my debugger highlighted line starts getting weird.

I.e. if I am debugging and suddenly I go back 3 lines, then something is wrong and I missed it.

So I drop the frame there, remember where the last line that was before I went backwards in my code, step in there, and continue debugging. thanks!