# Debugging at IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, command

I am curious how to execute previous line of code while debugging?

Currently, I see the following buttons:
- Step over;
- Step into;
- Force step into;
- Step out;

but no button "Step previous".

Comment: There is no such button :)

Comment: How then would you accomplish executing prev line? It is really weired ..

Comment: You can select the previous line and choose "evaluate expression", but that won't "rewind" to the previous line. It will just execute it once again.

Comment: You cannot do it. Though it sounds a simple thing to implement it is actually not so. Since most programs are stateful, once you've executed a statement that has a side-effect - executing the same thing again might cause unwanted and unexpected results.

Comment: You certainly can do it (not always), by dropping a frame, and steppping into that method again. I would say that most of the code will not have any side effect and it is safe to go through a method again, but that is something that cannot be generalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you cannot advance backwards while debugging code.  Since code runs are temporal, one should be able to re-run the code that they're debugging to narrow in on what specifically they want to observe in the debugger.

However, if you *really* want to be able to debug and step backwards, then [the Chronon plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Debugging+with+Chronon) is a viable option.  Note that you won't be dropped into a debug context immediately, and you won't be able to access any live evaluation, but this will allow you to debug your code by stepping forwards and backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could **Drop Frame** - it will return you to a previous method, so you can step on that line again. See [When using the Java debugger in Intellij what does "Drop Frame" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367816/when-using-the-java-debugger-in-intellij-what-does-drop-frame-mean)