# "Live" debugging in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After working with Java in Eclipse for 8 years I switched to IntelliJ Idea. Imagine the "cultural shock" I had hehehe
Anyway, there's one thing I really miss and not sure if IntelliJ supports it: easily editing Java code during a breakpoint.

In short, in Eclipse if i edit a line of code below the breakpoint and save the change, it will be automatically applied during program execution.
If I edit the line of code above the breakpoint (already executed), Eclipse debugger with move the "running cursor" to the beginning of the function whose code I changed and continue running from there including the changes I just added.

I know that in IntelliJ there's an option to build the module and approve "hot swap" of the code but the project I'm working on is humongous, build takes about 2 minutes and sometimes while investigating I need to make several changes and adjustments while debugging.

Is there an option or plugin for IntelliJ to automatically apply changes below the breakpoint or re-execute the function in case I made changes before the breakpoint?

Comment: By "build" do you mean "compile"?

Comment: Well, in IntellJ Idea there's a menu called "Build" and from there I choose "build project" or "Build module"

Comment: Don't do that. IntelliJ automatically compiles your edit. See [JetBrains "Edit running code with Hot Reload" article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Hot_Reload.html#Make_changes_when_running), although it does say auto reload only works on Windows. As an aside, I've been coding Java for a very long time and I've never been tempted to do this, nor have I known anyone else to. Another point is the build should be super fast because apps shouldn't be monolithic. It sounds like it's time to split your app up into smaller [microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).

Comment: Ah, I'm on Linux.... And i'm still just a cog in the company, it's not my project hence I was searching for alternative solution....

Answer (score 0):

HotSwap is [possible](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html) but there are some [limitations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#limitations).

Alternatively, you can use the Dynamic Code Evolution VM(DCEVM)  with unlimited support for reloading classes at runtime. There are plugins available that implement it.

[JRebel](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4441-jrebel-and-xrebel) (paid)

[Hotswap Agent](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9552-hotswapagent) (free)

Answer (score 0):

While your application is being debugged, IntelliJ will ask to hot reload the loaded classes if they are recompiled. This works on GNU+Linux as well; I have never had a problem with this.

If the code was already executed (e.g. your breakpoint is in the middle of a method), you can right-click the top frame in the "Frames" view and select "Drop frame". This will unwind the stack and you can enter the function again. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window.html or [When using the Java debugger in IntelliJ, what does "Drop Frame" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2367816/112968)

Note that any side-effects (print statements, modifying external collections, etc.) caused by the first method execution will *not* be rolled back.